# J2Mod - I/O exception - failed to read

Tags: java, exception, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am using for J2Mod java jar for my project. I am connected with the device through comport but, neither able to read nor write data into the device. Both time when I am trying to read or write data into the device getting the same exception. Whenever, Using QModMaster I am able to read data from the devices.

Connection Code -

```
SerialParameters parameters;
SerialConnection serialMaster;

try {
        parameters = new SerialParameters();

        parameters.setPortName((String) jComboBox4.getSelectedItem());
        //parameters.setCommPortId("/dev/ttyUSB1");
        parameters.setBaudRate(9600);
        parameters.setDatabits(8);
        parameters.setStopbits(1);
        parameters.setParity("none");
        // parameters.setEncoding("rtu");
        // parameters.setEcho(false);
        System.out.println("Connection Section" + parameters);
        serialMaster = new SerialConnection(parameters);

        serialMaster.open();
        System.out.println("Connection open :" + serialMaster.isOpen());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TankIQ_Configurator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Code for reading data -

```
ReadMultipleRegistersRequest readMultipleRegistersRequest;
ReadMultipleRegistersResponse readMultipleRegistersResponse;
ModbusSerialTransaction trans;    

trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(serialMaster);

Register[] register = {simpleRegister1, simpleRegister2};

int unitid = 1; //the unit identifier we will be talking to
int ref = 50; //the reference, where to start reading from
int count = 2; //the count of IR's to read
int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction

//4. Open the connection
try{
    //5. Prepare a request
    readMultipleRegistersRequest = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(50, 2);
    readMultipleRegistersRequest.setUnitID(unitid);
    readMultipleRegistersRequest.setHeadless();

    //6. Prepare a transaction
    trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(serialMaster);
    trans.setRequest(readMultipleRegistersRequest);

    int k = 0;
    do {
        trans.setTransDelayMS(1000);
        trans.execute();
        readMultipleRegistersResponse = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
        for (int n = 0; n < readMultipleRegistersResponse.getWordCount(); n++) {
            System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + readMultipleRegistersResponse.getRegisterValue(n));
        }
        k++;
    } while (k < repeat);
    serialMaster.close();//8. Close the connection
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WriteMultipleRegistersRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: none of your logs points to the code provided....

Comment: at least it's not obvious - where is `readResonse()` ?

Comment: @MartinFrank , Actually it's there. Line number 1503 is trans.execute(); ...   I wrote all these code in a single file that's why, it looks so big.

Comment: Below the trans.execute(); readResponse() is there.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out - it was not obvious at first glance =)

Comment: sorry, when i look into the source of [ModbusASCIITransport.java](https://github.com/autinitysystems/j2mod/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ghgande/j2mod/modbus/io/ModbusASCIITransport.java) i can follow up to `readResonse()` but i cannot find the method `readResponseIn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! all those who participated in this question.

Now, Let me explain, why I was getting this error.

Everything is fine with code except the `unitid`. `unitid` is nothing but slave address only. In my case slave address was 5.